# How to print a string in each line with some space from the first of the line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I did not write a clear subject because I didn't know what to write about it, sorry first of all.

What I want to reach is:

```
a
    a
        a
            a
                a
            a
        a
    a
a
```

With `for` loop I think I can reach this, but what I try is totally wrong.

Comment: That code has nothing to do with what you want to accomplish. Do you understand what each line of the code does? Or do you have an idea of what you expected each line to do?  More specifically: What do you expect the effect of `increment += 1` to be in that whole code? What is the idea behind `a * 2`?  Why is `a = 'a    '`?

Comment: BTW, the reason why you were unable to think of a good title is because you don't have a question. You should figure out what your question is (other than "help me", which is not a question).

Comment: Thanks @zvone, the `increment += 1`  was in my older code, sorry, it has nothing to do with my code. Regarding `a * 2` I was trying to produce the result which was totally wrong. As SO rules and what experts like you except, I just posted my attempts, regardless of being wrong. I do edit now my post to remove `increment` part.

Comment: An now you have code which prints `a * 2` ten times. That is not even an attempt to solve the task.

Comment: @zvone I know that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are locking for something like this.

```
a = 'a    '
space = '\t'

for c in range(5):
    print(space*c + a)

for c in range(5,0,-1):
    print(space*c + a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `increment` counter is useless in your code.

The way I would approach this is:

```
column_num = 0
for i in range(10):  # rows
    for j in range(10):  # cols
        if j == column_num:
            print("a", end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end='')
    print()  # newline
    column_num += 1

#then reverse:
column_num -= 1
for i in range(10): #rows
    for j in range(10): #cols
        if j == column_num:
            print("a", end = '')
        else:
            print(' ', end = '')
    print() #newline
    column_num -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but in Python `//` does not comment the line, instead `#` does that I used and worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it recursively:

```
def print_angle(s, start, end, direction):
    indent = "  "*start
    print(f"{indent}{s}")

    if start < end-1 and direction:
        print_angle(s, start+1, end, 1)
    elif start > 0:
        print_angle(s, start-1, end, 0)

print_angle('a', 0, 5, 1)
```

This prints:

```
a
   a
      a
        a
           a
        a
      a
   a
a
```

The idea here is:

**1.** Pass the desired character to print - **a** in this case.

**2.** Pass the starting point - 0 indents in this case.

**3.** Pass the ending point - 5 total to go.

**4.** Pass direction in which to go - 1 up, 0 down.

**5.** Go recursively up until you reach the end, preserve direction, initially up.

**6.** Go recursively down until you reach 0 and exit.